# Using IPv6 with Firefox on Windows 7

Tags: networking, firefox, ipv6

I have an intranet portal on which I've just enabled the IPv6 interface, and I'm trying to test it. (I can't disable the IPv4 interface yet.)

On a test client machine running Firefox on Windows 7,

1. When I tried to access the portal via hostname (e.g. http://portal.intranet), Firefox would

   a. Make the DNSv4 request (to the IPv4 DNS server)

   b. Get the IPv4 address of the portal

   c. And then access the portal via IPv4
2. When I tried to reach a non-existent hostname (e.g. http://doesnotexist.whatever), Firefox would

   a. Make the DNSv4 request (to the IPv4 DNS server)

   b. Get a "refused" response

   c. Make the DNSv6 request (to the IPv6 DNS server)

   ...
3. When I disabled IPv4 on the the test client (network settings), and tried to access the portal via hostname (e.g. http://portal.intranet), Firefox would either (sometimes)

   a. Just fail ("Firefox can't find the server at ..."), OR

   b. Make the DNSv6 request (to the IPv6 DNS server), get the response, and then fail ("Firefox can't find the server at ...") without even doing TCP SYN over IPv6
4. When I directly access the IPv6 address using Firefox (e.g. http://[1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888]), it works.

How can I get Firefox (on Windows 7) to work with (and PREFER) IPv6, without resorting to using the IPv6 address?

Comment: Please show the contents of the DNS zone for that hostname

Comment: PS: it doesn't matter if the DNS server is contracted over IPv4 or IPv6. There is nu such thing as DNSv4/DNSv6. It's the zone contents that matter

Comment: Try using the nslookup command to see what addresses are returned from the DNS server when FF queries it. Set the querytype to "A" and you should get the portal's IPv4 address. Set the querytype to "AAAA" and you should see its IPv6 address. As Sander Steffann says, it doesn't matter what protocol you talk to the DNS server over; it can return both kinds of addresses over both protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no AAAA DNS record for the hostname.

To entirely exclude the DNS server, you could temporary add the IPv6 address to the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file and the hostname.

If it then still gives issues, you need to look at the webserver configuration, if it does work correct then there is something with the DNS server.